# Are there any real life applications of Quantum Field Theory (QFT)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, applied-physics

When searching for QFT's applications, most articles and answers tend to mention how it is used to expand our understanding of physics, e.g. with the LHC.

So I'm wondering if you know of any examples (outside of particle/theoretical physics) where QFT has been used to develop new forms of technology, products, new processes, etc.

Thank you for any replies